# Admob ad not appearing in published app. Works fine in test mode

Tags: android, android-studio, admob

**[Solved] I had by mistake given the ad unit ID for an Interstitial Ad instead of Banner ad.Replaced with correct one. Now everything working fine.**

I have an admob ad unit integrated in my app. I am able to see the test ads on my emulator. For publishing the app I have removed the **.addTestDevice** from the code. The app have been published and made available on Google Play. However on the devices, the admob ads are not appearing. It shows blank area. I have configured a House ad for the ad unit in admob. Even the house ad is not displaying. In admob account report I am seeing nearly 1000 request but zero impression. The app was publised on week back and I have verified my ad unit id.

I am using the following code

1) In my activity onCreate

```
 AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
   //      .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
   //      .addTestDevice("B3EEABB8EE11C2Bxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
         .build();
 adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

2) Layout file

```
<!-- A DrawerLayout is intended to be used as the top-level content view using match_parent for both width and height to consume the full space available. -->
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">



    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:baselineAligned="false"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

        <!-- As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
              space available using match_parent in both dimensions. -->
        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-80501638xxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxx"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"/>

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/activity_main_webview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

    <!-- android:layout_gravity="start" tells DrawerLayout to treat
         this as a sliding drawer on the left side for left-to-right
         languages and on the right side for right-to-left languages.
         If you're not building against API 17 or higher, use
         android:layout_gravity="left" instead. -->
    <!-- The drawer is given a fixed width in dp and extends the full height of
         the container. -->
    <fragment android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:name="com.staffcorner.staffcorner.app.NavigationDrawerFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Requesting you help in solving the issue

The logs from Logcat (Obtained with filter I/Ads) 07-15 20:14:25.727

> 3483-3483/? I/Ads﹕ Starting ad request. 07-15 20:14:25.735
>   3483-3483/? I/Ads﹕ Use
>   AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("CEE7456B4FC811C99B9CC0xxxxxxxxxx") to
>   get test ads on this device. 07-15 20:14:25.760    3483-3483/? I/Ads﹕
>   Please set theme of AdActivity to @android:style/Theme.Translucent to
>   enable transparent background interstitial ad. 07-15 20:14:26.800 
>   24037-24037/? I/Ads﹕ JS: Document was loaded from Application Cache
>   with manifest
>   https : //googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40.appcache
>   (https : //googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40.html:0)
>   07-15 20:14:26.800  24037-24037/? I/Ads﹕ JS: Application Cache
>   Checking event
>   (https : //googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40.html:0)
>   07-15 20:14:28.858  24037-24037/? I/Ads﹕ JS: Application Cache
>   NoUpdate event
>   (https : //googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40.html:0)
>   07-15 20:14:28.891    3483-3623/? I/Ads﹕ No fill from ad server.

This was the log with app in admob test mode

> 07-15 20:52:41.054  13884-13884/com.staffcorner.staffcorner.app I/Ads﹕
>   Starting ad request. 07-15 20:52:41.071 
>   13884-13884/com.staffcorner.staffcorner.app I/Ads﹕ Please set theme of
>   AdActivity to @android:style/Theme.Translucent to enable transparent
>   background interstitial ad. 07-15 20:52:41.205 
>   13884-13945/com.staffcorner.staffcorner.app D/dalvikvm﹕ DEX prep
>   '/data/data/com.staffcorner.staffcorner.app/cache/ads217249737.jar':
>   unzip in 0ms, rewrite 130ms 07-15 20:52:41.916  24037-24037/? I/Ads﹕
>   JS: Document was loaded from Application Cache with manifest
>   https: // googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40.appcache
>   (https: // googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40.html:0)
>   07-15 20:52:41.917  24037-24037/? I/Ads﹕ JS: Application Cache
>   Checking event
>   (https: // googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40.html:0)
>   07-15 20:52:42.341  24037-24037/? I/Ads﹕ JS: Application Cache
>   NoUpdate event
>   (https: // googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40.html:0)
>   07-15 20:52:44.711  13884-13884/com.staffcorner.staffcorner.app I/Ads﹕
>   Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now. 07-15 20:52:44.718 
>   13884-13884/com.staffcorner.staffcorner.app I/Ads﹕ Ad finished
>   loading.

Comment: What do the logs say?

Comment: I am getting only Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("CEE7456B4FC811C99B9CC0xxxxxxxxxx") to get test ads on this device.

Comment: Admob generates much more log that. Add all of it to your question.

Comment: Thank you Mr. William. I had tried wrong filter for filtering the logs. Please find the logs, I have added at the end of my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason no ads are showing is because there is no ad fill. See

```
 07-15 20:14:28.891 3483-3623/? I/Ads﹕ No fill from ad server.
```

Comment: I dont have such thing appear in logcat but and not able to see the ads if i have remove the Ads from test mode.

Comment: Please let me know is there anything more to update.

Comment: @iDroidExplorer If you have requested an ad then your logs will contain ad request and ad result informaiton. If that doesn't help you out start a new question with your specifics.